# How to get all files name and size using jquery from <input type=file multiple>

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to get all files name and size using jquery from**

*My HTML*

```
<input type="file" id="images" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" id="send">
```

*My jQuery Code*

```
$('#send').click(function(){
var image1.name = $('#images').files[0].name;
var image1.size = $('#images').files[0].size;
alert(image1.name + ' - ' + image1.size);});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use files attribute from the input

```js
$('#send').click(function(){

var files = $('#images')[0].files;

for(var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
 console.log(files[i].name+'----'+files[i].size);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="images" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" id="send">
```

Comment: Its Going well! Thanks a Lot!! _/\_

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to iterate over the `files` property

```js
$('#send').on('click', function() {

  var files = $('#images').get(0).files;

  $.each(files, function(_, file) {
    console.log('name : ' + file.name + ' --- ', 'size : ' + file.size);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="file" id="images" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="button" id="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

how to accomplish this with multiple file inputs

`<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1"><br> <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2">`

**results:**

- filename1 - 111bytes
- filename2 - 456bytes
- Total bytes: 567bytes

Solution: multiple with 1 file input works great. For additional file inputs, simply repeat the code using different var names
now if only you can shorten the code to change number in a var name

example: var i = 0 or 1 or 2
var filename+i = filename1 or filename2 or filename3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).